# Applescript: open Dropbox preferences

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to open Dropbox preferences using Applescript?

I tried:

```
tell application "Dropbox" to open "Preferences"
```

I saw an earlier Stack Overflow posting but it's from 2011.

Answer (score 0):

I had to get a little create, but got it to work eventually. This script opens the Dropbox preferences:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dropbox"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click
    end tell
    tell window 1
        tell scroll area 1
            tell UI element 1
                tell group 33
                    click
                    keystroke "Preferences..."
                    keystroke return
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

However, after the click is performed, there is a 5 second delay before it performs the keystroke.
This is an issue which has been reported by a lot of people, but I haven't found a solution for this yet.